# Java List to Thymeleaf Form Inputs

Tags: java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have a list in Java from a query of a stored procedure, what I want to do is pass the values ​​of the list, to the inputs of the thymeleaf form, but I want to know how to pass that list in the controller and iterate it in the view, It is a Boostrap Modal, I would like help if I could do it with Ajax or with the th: fragment of thymeleaf.

**Model function**

```
public List getTypePlan(int id){
        List type = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection conn = AppConnection.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call SP_LEER_PFI_TIPOS_PLANES(?)}");
            cstmt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet results = cstmt.executeQuery();
            while (results.next()) {
                int cod_plan = results.getInt("cod_plan");
                String des_plan = results.getString("des_plan");
                int can_dias_plazo = results.getInt("can_dias_plazo");
                type.add(cod_plan);
                type.add(des_plan);
                type.add(can_dias_plazo);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
        return type;
    }
```

***Output example:*** `[1,General,3]`

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/typePlan/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String typePlan(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model m){
        Users_Access model = new Users_Access();
        m.addAttribute("type", model.getTypePlan(id));
        return "home :: type";
    }
}
```

**Boostrap Modal form**

```
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" id="TiposPlanes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">TIPOS DE PLANES</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-bodyh">
            <h6 class="modal-subtitle"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>  MODIFICAR TIPOS DE PLANES</h6>
            <h6 class="modal-subtitle">Presione click en el boton Modificar para grabar los cambios</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-form" th:fragment="type">
            <form class="form" th:method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label">Descripcion:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label">Diaz plazo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dias" name="dias">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">Modificar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, here is an example of how you could achieve this. First of all your `getTypePlan` method could look something like this (I used `CustomObject` as a custom model object for this, so you'll have to adjust to the name that fits your purpose):

```
    public List<CustomObject> getTypePlan(int id) throws Exception {
        List<CustomObject> type = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection conn = AppConnection.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call SP_LEER_PFI_TIPOS_PLANES(?)}");
            cstmt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet results = cstmt.executeQuery();
            while (results.next()) {
                int cod_plan = results.getInt("cod_plan");
                String des_plan = results.getString("des_plan");
                int can_dias_plazo = results.getInt("can_dias_plazo");

                CustomObject listObject = new CustomObject();
                listObject.setCodPlan(cod_plan);
                listObject.setDesPlan(des_plan);
                listObject.setCanDiasPlazo(can_dias_plazo);

                type.add(listObject);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return type;
    }
```

The model class in my case looks like this (I tried to keep it as close as possible to your example):

```
    public class CustomObject {

        private int codPlan;
        private String desPlan;
        private int canDiasPlazo;


        public int getCodPlan() {
            return codPlan;
        }

        public void setCodPlan(int codPlan) {
            this.codPlan = codPlan;
        }

        public String getDesPlan() {
            return desPlan;
        }

        public void setDesPlan(String desPlan) {
            this.desPlan = desPlan;
        }

        public int getCanDiasPlazo() {
            return canDiasPlazo;
        }

        public void setCanDiasPlazo(int canDiasPlazo) {
            this.canDiasPlazo = canDiasPlazo;
        }
    }
```

Your controller method would be adjusted to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/typePlan/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String typePlan(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model m){
        Users_Access model = new Users_Access();
        m.addAttribute("type", model.getTypePlan(id));
        return "home";
    }
}
```

And in your view could do the following to render the values of each object of `type` (which is returned by your `getTypePlan` method):

```
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" id="TiposPlanes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">TIPOS DE PLANES</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6 class="modal-subtitle"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>  MODIFICAR TIPOS DE PLANES</h6>
                    <h6 class="modal-subtitle">Presione click en el boton Modificar para grabar los cambios</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-form">

                    <!-- the customObject in the th:each is the iteratee and type is the list passed into the Model in the controller method -->
                    <form class="form" th:method="post" th:each="customObject : ${type}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="${customObject.getCodPlan()}" th:name="${customObject.getCodPlan()}" th:value="${customObject.getCodPlan()}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Descripcion:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="${customObject.getDesPlan()}" th:name="${customObject.getDesPlan()}" th:value="${customObject.getDesPlan()}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Diaz plazo:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="${customObject.getCanDiasPlazo()}" th:name="${customObject.getCanDiasPlazo()}" th:value="${customObject.getCanDiasPlazo()}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">Modificar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please bear in mind that this example works as expected with 1 object being added to the `type` list in the `getTypePlan` method, just like in your example. If you would have more results extracted from the database and added to the `type` list, then you would get multiple HTML forms rendered, which might not be the expected behavior.

So if you are going to expect multiple results (which you probably should expect), then you should think about organizing this a little bit different, but I'll leave that up to you as it's up to you how you would like to have that rendered. This example should help you to get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should your list into an Object

Try to follow this : [Thymeleaf List](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list)

Comment: Yes, but I haven't object because I am using stored procedure, my object is basically the stored procedure, or is it always necessary class of the object?

Comment: Well yes, you actually want to map your `ResultSet` obtained values into a model object(s) and add that/those object(s) into the `type` list. This will make reading the values for each object in the list in the view a piece of cake with the `th:each` helper tag.

Comment: Yes, Could you give me an example of how to do it please?